# How to change CSS id property depending upon screen size

Tags: html, css

I do know how to use media-screen functionality, but wanna ask you guys something else, something which I really needed for my project. Let me paste some code snippet so that I can elaborate you exactly what I'm looking for.
In below I'm pasting a css ID which I made for my site design:

```
#Disp_name {
color: #424854;
font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
font-size: 5.5em;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 105px;
/*margin: 200px 0 25px;*/
margin: 0px 0 25px;
text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
transition: color 0.3s ease 0s; }
```

Now I want when anyone open up my project from a small screen device, like
**When open up from 400> and <450px the font-size will be  4em and if >300 and <400px then 3em and if less than <300px then 2em.

What should I do? Please help

Comment: Use jQuery to calculate screen size and change it dynamically on page load

Comment: Lookup @media-query!

Comment: Can anybody please post a sample code, please? I'm not that much of experienced dev. Please post a code as an example.... Please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As DevIshone said, media queries are exactly what you're looking for. In that case it would look something like this

```
@media (max-width: 450px) and (min-width: 400px) {
    font-size: 4em;
}
@media (max-width: 400px) and (min-width: 300px) {
    font-size: 3em;
}
@media (max-width: 300px) {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just what I needed. This is why I love Stackoverflow... :)

Answer (score 3):

use media queries in your css

for example:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  .classname{
    font-size: 6em;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried the above code and when I'm decreasing the screen size the font size is not decreasing.
I'm use the below code:
`@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  #Disp_name{
    font-size: 2em !important;
  }
}`

Comment: you need to specify the max-device-width property for different width's like @zeaklous has mentioned,this was just an example as i mentioned above in my answer.